# Angular dist files || how can i run them locally without a server?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, angular

I am trying to create a desktop app. which uses Angular for frontend and c# for backend. the framework i am using is CefSharp. I tried running them locally by opening `index.html`, but it turns out that we need a server to run these files.

is there any workaround for this?

please help!

Comment: You can use local IIS. you can host application on IIS.

Comment: thx. i could try that.

Comment: If you want to make desktop application using angular not wpf, you can use electron (https://codeburst.io/how-to-build-a-desktop-application-with-electron-and-angular-ede2a1bd70cb).  Or you can choose ionic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found a solution to my problem and it was pretty simple, i had to download a node module **angular-http-server**

`npm install -g angular-http-server`

after installing this. i had to convert it to an executable so that i will be able to launch it from my c# project.

for converting this module into an executable i had to download **pkg** module.

`npm install -g pkg`

and using this i was able to convert that server into an executable. so that now it will even run on pc without node installed.

Comment: after the file has been converted in to .exe u need to move it to the dist folder. and then it will work.

Answer (score 3):

It is simple just install http-server module of NPM globally by running the below command:

**sudo npm install -g http-server**

And, then you can run **http-server** command in dist folder it should work.

Comment: thx, this would work on a pc with node installed. won't work on a pc without node.

Answer (score 0):

Once built, your project just consists of an html file and JS files.

Simply run `index.html` in your browser, it should work !

Comment: Where do you run it ? How did you build it ? Which error does it throws ?

Comment: ran it on Google chrome from the dist folder,  built with `ng build --prod` 

and it throws the following error
`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History'...:`

Comment: Strange ... Anyways, I just tested it, and it seems you can't anyway. If you want a fast solution though, you can install Python 3 and run `python -m http.server`